# Excel structured table references seem to rely on row numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel

As a simplified example, let's say I have a table (Table_1) of data like this, starting on row #1:

| Date | Month | Day | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01 | 01:00:00 | 01 | 01 |
| 01/01 | 02:00:00 | 01 | 01 |
| 01/01 | 03:00:00 | 01 | 01 |

And another table (Table_2) on another sheet that is just pulling the exact data, however Table_1 occupies A1:D3 on one sheet, while Table_2 occupies A2:D4 on another.  If I remove that first row everything works fine, but if not, I get this in Table_2:

| other stuff | here | not in | table |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

^ this is in row #1 but not in the Table_2 definition,
below starts on row #2

| Date | Month | Day | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01 | 01:00:00 | 01 | 01 |
| 01/01 | 02:00:00 | 01 | 01 |
| 01/01 | 03:00:00 | 01 | 01 |

The equation in that last column is `=INDIRECT("Table_1[@"&D$2&"]")`, where D2 is 'Data'

I'd really like to use a couple rows above the table for the functionality of the spreadsheet.  Is there another way to reframe that reference to ignore row numbers?

Comment: Try INDEX, MATCH functions. Or XLOOKUP function if it is available on your version of Excel.

Comment: Don't those kind of defeat the purpose of using tables?  I could do it all without using tables (and am currently leaning towards it) but the readability isn't as good.

Comment: When the `@` is used it will return the relative row, which works when used in the same table but in referencing another table they would need to be in the same row number or it would be off.  There are many limitations to what tables can do.

Comment: Oh interesting.  I had to put the @ in there to prevent a spill error, but I guess that doesn't work.  Ok I'll just remove all the tables.

Comment: I'm not clear why you use `INDIRECT` to get the value.  You could use FILTER in $D$3 to get the values for all the rows at once: `=FILTER(Table1,Table1[#Headers]=$D$2)`

Comment: Use XLOOKUP or Power Query. Relative referencing between Tables is the path of ruin.